# How to wrap a vertical overflow horizontally in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve something simple but can't think of a way to do in css.

I want to develop a page which should be horizontally scrollable and the text should keep on overflowing horizontally.

That is, a site like this: http://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/

But the horizontal grids are basically different divs. What I want is that the part of the first div should overflow automatically to it's right horizontally.

Like we do in research papers by creating a two horizontal division, like here: http://www.ieee.org/documents/transactions_journals.pdf

How to do that in CSS (with Javascript if needed)?

Comment: Could you use the CSS3 "columns" property as shown on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/)

Comment: @SteffiA. That should work! It was dumb of me to not being able to find something like that. You can post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the CSS3 "columns" property as shown on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/)

Answer (score 2):

As i understand the following should accomplish what you're trying to achieve :

```
<style>
    .wrapper {
        position:absolute;
        overflow-x:auto;
        overflow-y:hidden;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        background-color:green;
    }
    .inner-wrapper {
        width:20000px;
    }
    .column {
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid #000;
        background-color:blue;
        color:#fff;
        padding:20px;
        float:left;
    }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</div>
        <div class="column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</div>
        <div class="column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</div>
        <div class="column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vdu7a3a4/

You can set the width of the `.inner-wrapper` dynamically with javascript to match the width of your content.